# SSH — allow login with public key only / disable login with password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am quite new to server administration and I am not doing it very often. Today I wanted to secure my server, especially the ssh server. Is it possible to configure ssh so that only users can login if an public exists in the `autorized_keys` file? In other words: Disable login with password, only allow login if the public key exists. I searched the web for quite a while but could not find anything pointing me the direction.

Thanks in Ahead.

Answer (score 3):

In order to disable authentication using password, you have to disable the following settings in the configuration file of your sshd server (generally `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

Then reload the configuration:

```
$ sudo service ssh reload
```